# Using windows 10 tablet as additional monitor

Tags: windows-10

Apparently it is possible, but I had absolutely no luck making it work.

Built in Windows 10 functionality doesn't work - PC can't detect tablet as monitor.
Internet recommends SpaceDesk but no luck here either - it doesn't even offer option to connect anything, which implies it only works for android - PC.

Comment: You give no specifics and provide a rant rather than a question.  Someone here might be able to help you but I am going to vote to close this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.